# Undefined index usuario con session

Tags: php, mysql, session

como ya dije con anterioridad soy nueva trabajando con php y pues hoy tengo un problema a la hora de trabajar con sesiones. A la hora de hacer el login y una vez en el menu debe aparecer un mensaje dando la bienvenida al cliente, sin embargo me da ese error en el menu y no se que estoy haciendo mal. Adjunto el php del login y el de menu.
Se que en el menu php tengo errores de seguridad pero de momento no es lo imprescidible del proyecto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Login.php:**

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "equipamentos";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (!$conn)
{
    die("No hay conexión: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
session_start();
$nombre = $_POST["usuario"];
$pass = $_POST["contrasinal"];

$_SESSION["usuario"]= $nombre;


$q = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM novo_rexistro WHERE usuario = '$nombre' AND contrasinal = '$pass'");
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM novo_rexistro WHERE usuario = '$nombre'");
$quer = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM novo_rexistro WHERE contrasinal = '$pass'");
$r = mysqli_num_rows($q);
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$rn = mysqli_num_rows($quer);
if ($nombre==null){
header('Refresh:1; url=index.html'); echo 'campos vacios';
}
else if($r == 1 )
{
    header('Location: menu.php');
}
else if ($nr == 0)
{
  header('Refresh:1; url=registro.html'); echo 'Por favor registrate primero';

}
else if ($rn == 0){
header('Refresh:1; url=index.html'); echo 'La contraseña es incorrecta';
}
else if ($pass == null){
header('Refresh:1; url=index.html'); echo 'La contraseña esta vacia';
}
?>
```

**menu.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$nombre = $_SESSION["usuario"];
echo "Hola".$nombre;
 ?>
 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Menu de navegacion</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="diseño/menu.css">
   </head>

 <body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navegacion">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="equiposvenda.php">Equipos en venda</a></li>
                <li><a href="equiposaluguer.php">Equipos en aluguer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Servicios</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Servicio #1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Servicio #2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Servicio #3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li><a href="modificar.html">Modificar usuario</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  y agrega a la pregunta el mensaje de error completo. No sabemos sobre qué está dando `Undefined index` y de paso prueba tu variable de sesión haciendo un `var_dump($_SESSION);` allí donde estés teniendo problemas. También te recomiendo que evites usar nombres de archivos, carpetas, variables... con `ñ` o caracteres acentuados o especiales. Eso es problemático en ciertos contextos.

Comment: hecho! He añadido una captura del mensaje que me aparece

Comment: Prueba a agregar `exit()` después del location, algo asi: **`header('Location: menu.php'); exit();`** Luego, limpia la memoria caché y prueba de nuevo. Por favor haz un `var_dump($_SESSION);` también en `menu.php` y dinos lo que muestra.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Nuevamente tu comentario ha sido de gran ayuda! Solo con añadir el exit(); me ha funcionado. Si le añado el var_dump($_session) el mensaje es el siguiente: Holaantiaarray(1) { ["usuario"]=> string(5) "antia" }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalmente tienes que finalizar el script actual (mediante `exit()` o de otro modo) para que la sesión no se pierda al hacer la redirección.

Haciendo esto debería funcionar:

```
header('Location: menu.php');
exit();
```

Para más detalles puedes ver [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17242347/5587982) de StackOverflow en inglés.